# Can Modular Abilities get an extra 10% savings according to GURPS Supers rules if they don't grant skills?

Tags: gurps

I want the player characters to have lots of super-powers. For example, I want them to have inexpensive mental Modular Abilities with typically psionic abilities such as Psychokinesis and ESP and Mind Control (but no skills). Modular Abilities cost less if they are only mental. On the topic of Telekinesis, the main rulebook, page B92, says:

> Psychokinetic: Your ability is part of the Psychokinesis psi power (see p. 256). 
>   This makes it mental rather than physical. -10%

I want to give the players all available savings, but I want to avoid double-dipping by giving the same discount twice.

In a normal campaign, level 10 Telekinesis would cost 50 points as a physical power, but 45 points as a Psychokinetic mental power.

Now let us suppose that the player characters start off with Modular Abilities, mental advantages only. Assume each mental advantage costs 45 points, and only one can be used at a time, so this power is a one-slot modular ability, base cost 5 points, slot cost 3 points per advantage point. \$5+3\times45=190\$.

I think the basic cost should be \$190-19=171\$, because the quasimoral power modifier deducts   10%. But I see in GURPS Supers, p. 46, that a wizard can have an extra 10% savings due to “mental advantages only” (i.e. no skills are allowed). So perhaps the basic cost of this mental slot should be 152.

**Question: Which is more appropriate, 171 points or 152 points?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Powers*** page 64 says that Advantages Only or Skills Only (includes techniques): -10%. So you can totally get a 10% discount on a Modular Ability if it can't provide skills, and it's actually a very meaningful drawback.

However, beware of double-dipping when it comes to countermeasures: if your semi-moral power modifier includes a discount for certain Anti-Powers (***Powers*** page 20), then you should avoid *also* giving your Telekinesis a discount for the *same* Anti-Powers. Normally, psionic telekinesis assumes a -10% discount, of which 5% account for the mundane countermeasures and the other 5% for the Neutralise and similar counter-powers.

Finally, it is totally reasonable for you as a GM to declare that some or all forms of Telekinesis automatically count as mental powers in your setting, provided this fact is handled consistently and players are informed about the initial change.

Comment: Thanks! The easiest way might be to make the psychic powers semimoral but not psionic. Then I don't have to worry about antipsi countermeasures. Then Level 10 Telekinesis can be entirely a mental power, but granted by the moral forces and subject to moral countermeasures. Thus the slot would be 50 points, and any discount from the moral power modifier would be applied to the modular abilities, and not to the 50-point slot power. Thus [5+(3*50)]*.8=124 points.

Comment: @Long Beware of potentially double-dipping by applying the -5% for Countermeasures to both the Modular Ability and the Telekinesis **if** your Semimoral power modifier includes it. (Or I misunderstood what you intend to do with modular ability modifiers vs. TK modifiers.)